# VSCode editor is showing errors that function `x` doesn't exist but the project builds without error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have two very simple blocks of code, my editor throws an error however the project itself builds without error.

In this block I took a command line arg and converted it to a string, and I needed to convert it back to a char to use it in `fopen`, so I did this:

```cpp
  const char* path = this->path.c_str();
  FILE* fp = fopen(path, "rb");
```

However, in the editor I get this error which doesn't show up when I build the project:

```
class "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" has no member "c_str"
```

Again, I am trying to use a method `push_back()` on a vector, and it also throws an error in the editor but not when built.

```
class Image {
public:
  vector<Color> data;

  void addColor(shared_ptr<Color>& color) {
    this->data.push_back(*color);
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
class "std::vector<Color, std::allocator<Color>>" has no member "push_back"
```

I am using the [C/C++ plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) by microsoft. Is there some sort of configuration that I have wrong?

I have only updated a few items. Aside from those, everything is set to the default values.

```json
{
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseUpdateDelay": 500,
    "C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.updateDelay": 250,
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_path": "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\clang-format.exe",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
    "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
      "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{\"BasedOnStyle\": \"Google\",\"UseTab\": \"Never\",\"IndentWidth\": 2,\"TabWidth\": 2,\"BreakBeforeBraces\": \"Attach\",\"AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine\": false,\"IndentCaseLabels\": false,\"ColumnLimit\": 0,\"AccessModifierOffset\": -2,\"NamespaceIndentation\": \"All\",\"FixNamespaceComments\": false,}"
}
```

Comment: Only a C++ compiler can fully understand the source code to a C++ program. C++ is very complicated. Your text editor is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: [`C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp#_system-includes) is not set.

Comment: @273K I just noticed that, that is in the workspace file, so there is another setting that I modified. I updated the post.

Comment: I guess not, I am using `includePath`

Comment: I think running `C\C++: Select IntelliSense Configuration...` may have fixed it...

Comment: so the problem was just that you didn't select the config you wrote? I'm also curious if this is a language standard version thing. is `push_back` a c++11-and-up thing? If so, you make sure you specify `C_Cpp.default.cppStandard`.